# SQL how to join on another field if the first field has letters in it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL join that looks like this

```
INNER JOIN UPLOAD PH on cast(p.PickTicket_Number as varchar(20))=PH.FIELD004
```

However, sometimes, the field I really want to join on is PH.FIELD003. This happens when PH.FIELD004 is a different field that has letters in it. How do I include a condition in the ON clause where if field004 does not have letters in it (is numeric), it joins just like that above, but if it does have letters in it, it instead joins on the pickticket number = field003?

Comment: What is the datatype of all three columns involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can express the logic like this:

```
UPLOAD PH 
ON cast(p.PickTicket_Number as varchar(20)) = PH.FIELD004 OR
   (TRY_CONVERT(int, PH.FIELD004) IS NULL AND
    CAST(p.PickTicket_Number as varchar(20)) = PH.FIELD003
   )
```

Notes:

- This checks that `FIELD004` cannot be converted to an `INT`.  This is hopefully close enough to "has letters in it".  If not, you can use a `CASE` expression with `LIKE`.
- `OR` is a performance killer for `JOIN` conditions.  Function calls (say for conversion) also impede the optimizer.
- If performance is an issue, ask a *new* question.
- I am guessing the "number" value is an `INT`; if not, change to the appropriate type.
- Converting numbers to strings for comparison can be dangerous.  I've had problems with leading 0's, for example.

Because of the last issue, I would recommend:

```
UPLOAD PH 
ON TRY_CONVERT(INT, PH.FIELD004) = p.PickTicket_Number  OR
   (TRY_CONVERT(int, PH.FIELD004) IS NULL AND
    p.PickTicket_Number= PH.FIELD003
   )
```